# Grid template columns should adjust based on size of div

Tags: css, sass, flexbox, css-grid

I am using display:grid and grid-template-columns for a div in my html page. Using media queries I am updating the number of columns in each row for this grid.

@media screen and (min-width: 200px) and (max-width:767.5px){
.options-container {
display: grid;
grid-template-columns: 100%;
}

}

@media screen and (min-width: 768px) {
.options-container {
display: grid;
grid-template-columns: 48% 48%;
column-gap: 4%;
}

}

Based on the above code, it shown one column upto 767.5px and once we cross 768px it shows 2 columns per row. All this code is working as expected.

But when the parent div width is reduced to 200px, since the screen size is still 768px it shows 2 columns per row. At this point since the parent div width is 200px I want to show only one column per row.I understand the media queries will not work since it is based on the width of the device and not the parent div. Can you please let me know how I achieve the functionality of updating number of columns per row in the grid based on parent div.

Comment: remove `and (min-width: 200px)` or creat a new rule from `@media screen and (max-width: 199px) {/* reset: parent to display block or grid-template-columns to your needs*/}` .

Comment: @G-Cyrillus The window width is 1024px, the div which has display: grid is wrapped inside one more main div. If this main div width is reduced then the div with display:grid is still applying the media query applicable for 1024px.

Comment: this happens probably because your min-width:768px comes after max-width:767px in your style sheet. last matching rule/selector  is then applied and overrides previous. Also specifity could be in the way, obviously not here.

Comment: You will find this link interesting https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Container_Queries